# xcode - Core Data With parent entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, core-data

Hello at this point on my project I cant make 2 table views with relationship like this:

Table1(contains the "Parent" entity) >>> Table2(contains the "Child" entity)
example:
Table1:
Jerry
Steven
Larry

and once I click on someone's name I want to see his children names(example):
Dan
Stan

(Table1 and Table2 are both dynamic).

That'll be really awesome if someone can give me a source code or an example how to do it between classes and core data.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: do you have hands on experience of working with CoreData ?

Comment: @CodenameLambda1 I tried to work with it but only with one attribute and one table view. now I am trying to work with 2 table views and I couldnt find any tutorial for this.

Comment: @TomHarrington I have tried to fetch the parent data between classes and use it with the child entity like (parent.child="Jack()example")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your TableViewController for parent is already populated, you want to use the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to pass the Parent object and access the relationship with Child.

You should check out some tutorials to become familiar with Core Data. These are a pretty good starting point:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StMBHzA7h18